# Using Embedded Assets Plugin With Element API

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi, plugin-embeddedassets

When using the [Element API](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api), how do you go about using the [Embedded Assets plugin](https://github.com/benjamminf/craft-embedded-assets)?

With a regular asset, in the API transformer you can pull out assets and include them like this:

```
'transformer' => function(craft\elements\Entry $entry) {
    // Create an array of all the photo URLs
    $photos = [];
    foreach ($entry->photos->all() as $photo) {
        $photos[] = $photo->url;
    }

    return [
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'url' => $entry->url,
        'description' => (string)$entry->description,
        'photos' => $photos
    ];
},
```

This approach however gives me the URL to the **json file** that Embedded Assets uses to store some information about the video.

Is there a better way than parsing that file as json in php and pulling the iframe from that? Is there some plugin code that can be used to handle this more elegantly?

Comment: Hi James, what are you trying to get out of the Embed Assets and return?

Comment: Hi Ryan. I'm hoping to pull out either the "code" attribute (the iframe). I know I could parse the json file and pull it out that way, but I imagine there's a "proper" way to do it using plugin code.